# Keeping a modal dialog vertically centered after page resize

Tags: html, css, html5dialog

When using the `<dialog>` element with `.showModal()`, the dialog displays horizontally and vertically centered on the page.  However, if the browser window is then resized, the dialog is no longer centered.

[image: JSFiddle Screenshot]

```
<dialog>
  <h1>
    Test Dialog
  </h1>
  <p>
    This is a test modal dialog.
  </p>
</dialog>
```

```
document.querySelector('dialog').showModal();
```

JSFiddle Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/ctob5j7u/

What's the appropriate way to style the dialog to keep it centered on the page?  (Or, is that appropriate to do?  I understand that browsers in the future may handle `showModal()` totally differently, particularly on mobile.)

Comment: I think you're falling afoul of JSFiddle's own window styles. Can you try changing the display settings (top right) to 'right results'? Resize your result panel and see if it behaves as you expect.

Comment: @chicgeek I clarified the question and added a screenshot.  I have this problem in my application, or on JSFiddle, or anywhere.  The key is, vertical centering.  Sorry, I should have made that clarification originally.

Comment: add the following to `dialog` `position: absolute;  top: 50%; transform: translatey(-50%);` Works in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following to `dialog` `position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translatey(-50%);` Works in jsfiddle